# Error 403 returned

Tags: web-hosting

What do I need to do in order to avoid the message below?
I am hosting my first website site on GoDaddy. I did so watching the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvyWeTXCSKk&t=152s).

I ran a tiny bit of HTML as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1>
    Hello
</h1>
</html>
```

I go to the domain name mathtyper.com that I recently purchased through GoDaddy, and I get the following message.

[image]

Comment: There is not enough info here to fully diagnose the problem.   There are hundreds of possible causes of forbidden errors.   The first step is to consult your servers error log for additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to double check that -

- Your file is called index.html
- The permissions on the file are 644 or better
- The index file is located in the public_html subdirectory.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works :)